# Why usage of dynamic throws exception in runtime?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

I have an external dll I'm loading into my appdomain during runtime.

I'm creating an instance of a class from that assembly into a local dynamic variable.

As far as I understood the usage of dynamic in C#, I can simply call a method of it, which will be resolved at run time...

Using this approach, the following code gets me a runtime "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Get'" exception.

I'll try to illustrate the structure as I can't expose the actual code.

External dll name: `a.b.c`

```
namespace Ext
{
  public static class FactoryCreator
  {
    public static ProxyFactory CreateFactory()
    {
        return new ProxyFactory();
    }
  }


  public interface FactoryIfc
  {
    Proxy Get();
  }

  internal class ProxyFactory: FactoryIfc
  {
    private Proxy proxy;

    public Proxy Get()
    {
      if (this.proxy == null)
        this.proxy = <a method to create a proxy>
      return this.proxy;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using the following code

```
var assembly = "a.b.c, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<key>,processorArchitecture=MSIL";
var instName = "Ext.FactoryCreator";
dynamic factoryCreator = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load(assembly).GetType(instName).GetMethod("CreateFactory").Invoke(null, new object[0]);
dynamic proxy = factoryCreator.Get();
```

I understand that for `FactoryCreator` dynamic variable, I need to get the Type and invoke the static method of it, but.. as I said, it is throwing an exception "'object' does not contains a definition for 'Get'" - at the `factory.Get()` statement - while I would expect `dynamic factory` to be resolve automatically to the object and service the `Get()` call.

Observing the situation under a debug session, I can clearly see the `Get` method using `factory.GetType().GetMethods()` in the quickwatch window.

Can you explain what is happening?

[image]

Must I use `factory.GetType().GetMethod("Get")` followed by an `Invoke`? I thought the power of `dynamic` should work this out automatically in runtime...

Comment: `ProxyFactory` isn't a public type, so it doesn't really have a public API to speak of, if you're not in the same assembly; `dynamic` tries to respect accessibility. I'm not sure how that code, compiles, though - since `ProxyFactory` is used as a return type on a public API

Comment: @MarcGravell: I've added the missing ifc. Is still dynamic can't service the `Get()`? the interface is public

Comment: Presumably the real `FactoryCreator` returns the interface type? That would explain my second question. But no: interface APIs aren't directly reachable here unless they're part of the public API. This type isn't public, so it *has no* public API, in the full accessibility rules sense. I wonder if the real trick here is to move the interface out to a separate assembly that both these code blocks can reference, and lose the `dynamic` usage completely. To see interface methods, you need to be going via the interface - which `dynamic` does not do (unless they're also on the public API surface)

Comment: To second Marcs comments, this is not the real code as it does not compile. I would recommend you posting some actual, real, code. Otherwise you might be masking the real reason for the problem. As Marc has said, it is not possible to compile a public class returning an internal type from a method. Therefore this is not the real code.

Comment: Your code 1) does not compile 2) does not make much sense -  `GetType(instName).GetMethod("CreateFactory").Invoke(null, new object[0])` should already had invoked `CreateFactory` so `factoryCreator` is actually `ProxyFactory` so you should call `Get` on it. Can you please post an actual repro?

Comment: you are all correct, indeed the code i posted is not the real one. Let me try and build something that compiles and shows the situation. As I wrote in the question, I can't post the real code due to IP reasons...